# Select 2nd column value if first is null using MySQL?

Tags: mysql

How to select 2nd column's value if the 1st column value is null.

**For example:** Table bookings contains records like

```
id | sold_price | contract_price
---------------------------------
1  | 10000      | 150000
---------------------------------
2  |            | 20000
```

I am looking for some mysql query like

```
    Select SUM
           (If (bookings.sold_price !=NULL) 
            Else bookings.contract_price)
    FROM bookings 
    Where id=2
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `coalesce()` function

```
Select SUM(coalesce(bookings.sold_price,bookings.contract_price)) 
from tablename
where id=2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    SUM(COALESCE(sold_price, contract_price))
FROM
    table_bookings
WHERE
    id = 2;
```

`coalesce` returns the first non-null value in a list.

Answer (score 1):

You could use  a case when  is null

```
Select sum( case when bookings.sold_price  is null 
         then bookings.contract_price else bookings.sold_price  end)
from my_table  
where id = 2
```

or in mysql you could use ifnull

```
Select sum( ifnull(bookings.sold_price , bookings.contract_price) )
from my_table  
where id = 2
```